# JMX connection timeout

Tags: java, timeout, profiling, jmx

I am using JVM monitor to profile an application on a remote server. The connection towards the remote server is very slow and I always get "The connection timed out" when I try to connect. I had a similar problem when I was remote debuging this application and I solved it by increasing the timeout period. However, I am unable to find a way to do this for JMX connection. I am sure I started my application with right arguments and that firewall is not a problem.

Comment: Add some code to your question, it's often helpful.

Comment: Who is timing out? The monitor or the monitored application? Maybe starting eclipse with `eclipse -vmargs -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=60000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=60000`or similar can help. Try connectiong through URL, then.